# Get column information from MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a script that, so far, displays the table name, and underneath that it displays an array for each column and information about each one.

```
<?php

include_once('include/connect.php'); 

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM mydb";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

echo "<b>{$row[0]}</b><br>";

$listcols = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$row[0]}");

while ($rowz = mysql_fetch_assoc($listcols)) {
       print_r($rowz);echo "<br>";
    }

}


mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

I was wondering how I'd go about setting it so that it'll create something like "CREATE TABLE *tablenameresult* (column1 int (2), column3 char(20)..." and so on and so on for each table.

Is this possible since the information is displayed as an array?

Comment: you want to dump it so perhaps you can restore elsewhere?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: @Popnoodles that is correct. We don't have a phpmyadmin and we want to move the tables to a different server, but we don't need any of the information from the tables.

Comment: @tadman our server is still on PHP 4, so for now we will use the depreciated version until next year when we upgrade everything

Comment: It doesn't have details about indexes, you can get that with `show index from tablename`. What you're doing would probably be easier done with queries against the tables in `information_schema`, since you can write joins to collect all the information in a single query.

Comment: Why not use `mysqldump` from the CLI?

Comment: @Barmar no one in the company knows who has access to the CLI. currently we have to write scripts and upload them with FTP to get information we need so that we can move to a new server next month

Comment: A really old PHP 4 compatible version of phpmyadmin might do the trick here rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export all data to new site with a PHP script, you could use this:

```
$password = "*****";    
exec('mysqldump -u your_user -h localhost -p'.$password.' test_django',  $out, $return);

var_dump($out);
```

You could see that -p and $password don't have whitespaces.

DON'T use "exec" to a public file

I hope this script help you

Comment: OP don't want to export. He needs to visualize the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Found this code on another forum. This works perfectly for what I need. Posting this here in case anyone else needs help with this issue.

```
<?php 
// show_tables.php 

$conn= mysql_connect('host','user','pass') 
    OR die('Connection error'); 
$database= 'databasename'; 
mysql_select_db($database); 
$sql1= 'SHOW TABLES FROM ' .$database; 
$res1= mysql_query($sql1) OR die('Query 1 error:<br />' .mysql_error()); 

echo '<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0 width="90%">'; 
while ( $row= mysql_fetch_row($res1) ) 
{ 
echo '<tr>'; 
echo '<td valign="top" align="center">' .$row[0]. '</td>'; 
echo '<td>'; 
$sql2= 'SHOW CREATE TABLE ' .$row[0]; 
$res2= mysql_query($sql2) OR die('Query 2 error:<br />' .mysql_error()); 
while ( $table_def= mysql_fetch_row($res2) ) 
{ 
    for ($i=1; $i<count($table_def); $i++) 
    { 
        echo '<pre>' .$table_def[$i]. '</pre>'; 
    } 
} 
echo '</tr>'; 
} 
echo '</table>'; 
?>
```